# Большое значение корреляции - текстурного признака Харалика (Accord.NET)

Tags: c#, обработка-изображений, emgucv, текстура

Рассчитываю текстурные признаки Харалика, использую Accord.NET.
Значение корреляции получается очень большое, например, 464485811,26394. Не в диапазоне от -1 до 1.
С чем это связано? В чём ошибка?

Например, для изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Корреляция - 66954519,712237

```
     // Загружаю файл
       OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imgH = new Image<Gray, byte>(ofd.FileName);
            }


var glcm = new GrayLevelCooccurrenceMatrix(distance: 1, degree:  CooccurrenceDegree.Degree0, normalize: true, autoGray:true);

Bitmap BmpInput = imgH.ToBitmap();

double[,] matrix = glcm.Compute(BmpInput);

HaralickDescriptor haralick = new HaralickDescriptor(matrix);
   
var f01 = haralick.F01.ToString();
var f02 = haralick.F02.ToString();
var f03 = haralick.F03.ToString();
// ... и так далее до f014
// ... вывод переменных в dataGridView
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы не привели код, можно только гадать. Я предполагаю, что вы не указали соответствующий [параметр](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Imaging_Haralick__ctor_1.htm):

```
normalize = true
```

> normalize
>
> ```
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> Whether to normalize generated histograms. Default is false.
> ```

Comment: Добавила в вопрос код. Параметр был normalize: true.

Comment: @Мария Хорошо. Осталось добавить входные данные, чтобы можно было что-то самостоятельно проверить.

Comment: Добавила изображение и полученное значение. Спасибо.

Comment: @Мария Осталось добавить код как вы читаете файл с картинкой в нужный формат, который можно скормить в Accord. Я пытался сам, но тут мои компетенции пока всё.

Comment: Добавила. Спасибо.

Comment: @Мария `Image<Gray, byte>` - из какого пространства `Image`, из какого пространства `Gray`? А то мне гадать приходится, пока не смог угадать.

Comment: Не указала, что использую Emgu CV.

Comment: @Мария Ага, ну я так и понял, погуглив, но сомневался. На будущее сразу всё это указывайте в вопросе. Какие-то вещи в виде тегов, какие-то просто в тексте.

Comment: Пока я застрял на ошибке `Ошибка CS1929 "Image<Gray, byte>" не содержит определение для "ToBitmap", и наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод расширения "Tools.ToBitmap(byte[*,*])" требует наличия получателя типа "byte[*,*]".`

Comment: Возможно, ошибка связана с версией. Я использую EmguCV 4.1.1.3497.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15406235/convert-emgucv-image-to-system-drawing-bitmap